# Android SDCard write access without picking the sdcard

Tags: android, android-file

We have an app which reads files from an sd-card mounted over USB-OTG. Basically the user connects a device(which acts as an usb-drive) to his phone, and our app responds to the ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED intent, filtered on usb-device, and copies files from the device into a local sqlite db, pending remote upload. We ensure we have android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and then constructs file paths from mount point we get from the media-mounted event, this all works fine.

Now we wanted to delete the files from the device after copying it, and whatever I tried I just got access denied when trying to delete files or folders...

From what I can gather from this post: https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html I should probably use the "Storage Access Framework", and I can probably make it work if I force the user to first select the root of the usb drive, but this seems like a really bad user experience... My question is: how(if possible) can I(using "SAF") ask for permission to a named android mount point(gotten from media mounted intent, e.g. /storage/3F74-6221) WITHOUT forcing user to pick this location that I already know where is?

Comment: "this all works fine" -- have you tried it on Android 10 or R? "My question is..." -- if you can use `StorageManager` to find the desired `StorageVolume`, you can use [`createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageVolume?hl=en#createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()) on Android 10+ and [`createAccessIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageVolume?hl=en#createAccessIntent(java.lang.String)) on older devices.

Comment: I havent tested on Android 10, no. Your suggestion should be possible, but I already KNOW the path of the sd-card, do I really have to ask the user AGAIN what it is, with the possibility of him picking the WRONG one, only for gaining access to it? Every example of SAF I see starts with the user picking a folder, but I already know the folder...

Comment: `, do I really have to ask the user AGAIN what it is, with the possibility of him picking the WRONG one,`. No. As the user will not pick then but only confirm the path you propose.

Comment: "I already KNOW the path of the sd-card" -- presently, perhaps. Device manufacturers might screw up that broadcast. Plus, I would not be the least bit surprised if that broadcast is removed in future Android versions. "do I really have to ask the user AGAIN what it is" -- yes. It's not a question of *knowledge*, but a question of *permission*. "this all works fine" -- it shouldn't, as we have not had guaranteed access to arbitrary locations on removable storage since Android 4.4.

Comment: Let the users put the files in the app specific directory on the sd card and you are ready without any permission. And fine old file access.

Comment: Thnx @CommonsWare, but the documentation is pretty specific: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED It says "The path to the mount point for the mounted media is contained in the Intent.mData field." They cant really remove this broadcast can they?

Comment: You are assuming that the Android Compatibility Test Suite checks that broadcast, checks that value, and checks the validity of that value. And, you are assuming that a post-launch firmware update does not turn around and break that broadcast. *Trying* to use that broadcast in your app is perfectly reasonable, but I would not assume that it is 100% reliable.